# await Firebase.initializeApp(); causes error first time working but after my computer down and on not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "",
        appId: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
      ),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Answer (score 1):

You should add your Firebase project to your Flutter App.
Here is the link how to do that https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web.
After adding it properly, Firebase generates a config file then your code will be

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer that's because

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

is deprecated so becareful (Most of the content is using the old way).